# Finding a tighter bound given sum and sum of squares

Tags: inequality, optimization, sums-of-squares

Let $x_1, ..., x_{25}>0$ be such that $\sum_{i=1}^{25}{x_i} = 4350$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{25}{x_i^2} = 757770.25$.

From the first equality alone, we know that at least one of the $x_i$'s must be less than or equal to $\frac{4350}{25}=174$. From the second equality alone, we know that at least one of the $x_i$'s must be less than or equal to $\sqrt{\frac{757770.25}{25}}=174.1$, which is less useful than the first bound. My question is whether we can get a better bound, i.e. to find the least upper bound of $\min{\{x_1, ..., x_{25}\}}$, when we use both equalities together. I appreciate any comments or hints.

Comment: Maximilian Janish: I read your now deleted comment. Please consider putting it as an answer (after checking it, but it looks right to me...).

Comment: @coffeemath It’s wrong because the sum of the $x_i$ is not what it should be .

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch That's interesting. I wonder if there's any analytical way of obtaining this bound.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Unless I'm doing something wrong, with your Mathematica code I obtain $170.475$, and not $157.327$.

Comment: Sure, using Mathematica 11.1.1, I get $170.475$ with
$$\{z(1)\to 170.481,z(2)\to 174.898,z(3)\to 170.941,z(4)\to 182.717,z(5)\to    170.481,z(6)\to 170.484,z(7)\to 175.845,z(8)\to 179.947,z(9)\to 170.481,z(10)\to    170.482,z(11)\to 170.484,z(12)\to 181.417,z(13)\to 192.231,z(14)\to 186.727,z(15)\to    170.495,z(16)\to 170.488,z(17)\to 176.297,z(18)\to 170.477,z(19)\to 170.49,z(20)\to    170.478,z(21)\to 170.481,z(22)\to 170.48,z(23)\to 170.475,z(24)\to 171.742,z(25)\to    170.48\}.$$

Comment: @projectilemotion This is not a global maximum. Maybe you can coax Mathematica to find a better solution by explicitly imposing $x_1\le\dots\le x_{25}$ and maximizing $x_1$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's some nontrivial improvement at least. Suppose that $m=\min\{x_1,\dots,x_{25}\}\le174$, and write $x_j = m + t_j$. Then $\sum x_j = 4350$ means $\sum t_j = 4350 - 25m$, while $757770.25 = \sum x_j^2 = \sum (m^2 + 2m t_j + t_j^2)$ means
\begin{align*}
\sum t_j^2 &= 757770.25 - 25m^2 - 2m \sum t_j \\
&= 757770.25 - 25m^2 - 2m(4350 - 25m) = 757770.25 - 8700m + 25m^2.
\end{align*}
Finally, the fact that the $t_j$ are all nonnegative means that $(\sum t_j)^2 \ge \sum t_j^2$; in other words, we must have
$$
(4350 - 25m)^2 - (757770.25 - 8700m + 25m^2) \ge 0.
$$
But now the quadratic equation implies that $m \le \dfrac{20880 - 59\sqrt6}{120}$, which is a little less than $172.8$.

*Edited to add*: as RobPratt pointed out, this bound is actually optimal! If $x_1=\cdots=x_{24}=\dfrac{20880 - 59\sqrt6}{120}$ and $x_{25} = 4350 - 24x_1 = \dfrac{870+59 \sqrt{6}}5$, then $\sum x_j = 4350$ and $\sum x_j^2 = 757770.25$ exactly.

Comment: Indeed, taking $x_1=\dots=x_{24}=\frac{20880 - 59\sqrt6}{120}$ and $x_{25}=4350-24\frac{20880 - 59\sqrt6}{120}$ is feasible and yields $\min_i x_i = \frac{20880 - 59\sqrt6}{120}$.

Comment: This is indeed a very elegant solution. Thank you all for the efforts.